# The probability that a base exists in the span of a set of random vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Let each element of vector $x_{n \times 1}$ be a random variable which could be equal to one or zero with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. We have $k$ such vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k$. Assuming all operations are over GF(2), what is the probability that the base vector $e_1=[1,0,0,\dots,0]^T$ is spanned by vectors $x_1,\dots,x_k$. This problem is closely related to the one in

[Expected number of random binary vectors to make matrix of order n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/589725/expected-number-of-random-binary-vectors-to-make-matrix-of-order-n)

The difference is we are only interested in the probability of spanning one specific vector. Also, what is the average value of k for which $e_1$ is spanned with probability one?

Comment: Here’s what I think is a sketch of an answer to your question: Compute the probabilities $P(k,r)$ that the rank of the span of the $x_i$ is $r$. (This might help you do that: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/324260.) Then note that probability that $e_1$ is in a subspace $V$ given only that the rank of $V$ is $k$ is $\frac{2^k-1}{2^n-1}$ (the same as the probability that any specific nonzero vector is). Then the probability you seek is $\sum_{r=0}^n P(k,r)\frac{2^k-1}{2^n-1}$.

Comment: Never mind! I was able to open the link. Thank you for your help. It solves the problem.

Comment: Ah, the period at the end of the sentence became part of the link in my comment. For anyone else having trouble, go to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/324260 .